# AdMob test ads no longer appear, showing No ad config error message

Tags: java, android, admob

I'm trying to test the ads in my app, I'm using the following test ads unit :

```
<string name="APP_ID">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713</string>
<string name="INTERSTITIAL_ADMOB">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712</string>


InterstitialAd.load(activity, StringUtils.getString(R.string.INTERSTITIAL_ADMOB), adRequest, new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                    interstitialAd.show(activity);
                    interstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                            adsCallBack.onAdClosed();
                            Log.d("TAG", "The ad was dismissed.");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                            Log.d("TAG", "The ad was shown.");
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                    Log.d("AdMob", "==> " +loadAdError.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

I always get : **No ad config**

I've added the following line to my **app-ads.txt**

```
google.com, pub-3940256099942544, DIRECT, f08c47fec0942fa0
```

AdMob SDK :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.4.0'
```

Response Info :

```
   {
      "Response ID": "null",
      "Mediation Adapter Class Name": "",
      "Adapter Responses": []
    }
```

**NOTE : The real ads are working fine, but the test one no.**

Comment: Did you well add your test mobile as test device ?

Comment: @Elikill58 thank you for your comment, I've two devices, one is registered as test device, and the other one no, but ads not working on both of them

Comment: sometimes test ads fails with no explanation.. if real ads are showing correctly. you should be all good to go-live. To avoid accidental clicks use "enable test devices" scenario instead.

Comment: @AmodGokhale thank you for your comment, right now, I'm facing the ad limit issue (for the 20 times), I just want to test the ads to make sure, if AdMob re-serve the ads in my apps, everything will work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is updating the AdMob SDK to ***20.5.0***